# How to find sum of list of lists using for-loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, sum

```
prefer_indic = [[[0, 4, 6, 5, 45, 1], [2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 1]],[[0, 0.27, 6, 7, 32, 3], [0.01, 0.39, 0, 0, 0, 0]]]
```

I want to create a sum list that will add every value from every list of lists with each corresponding ones.
To be accurate i want:

`sum = [[0+0, 4+0.27, 6+6, 5+7, 45+32, 1+3], [2+0.1, 3+0.39, 5+0, 6+0, 7+0, 1+0]]`

I want to do it with a for loop so that i can use the same algorithm for bigger list of lists.I made the example simple to make it more readable. I have python 2.7 .

Comment: If your lists are all the same length, which I suspect they are, you could use a 3D `numpy` array and calculate the sum depthwise. It should be faster than a for loop for very large arrays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`zip()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to pair up elements from 2 or more lists, then use [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) to add up the combined values:

```
summed = [[sum(zipped) for zipped in zip(*column)] for column in zip(*prefer_indic)]
```

Note the `zip(*prefer_indic)` call, which *transposes* your matrix so that you pair up the 'columns' of your nested lists, not the rows.

If your lists are larger, it may be beneficial to using the [*iterative* version of `zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip); use the [`future_builtins.zip()` location](https://docs.python.org/2/library/future_builtins.html#future_builtins.zip) and your code is automatically forward-compatible with Python 3:

```
try:
    from future_builtins import zip
except ImportError:
    # Python 3

summed = [[sum(zipped) for zipped in zip(*column)] for column in zip(*prefer_indic)]
```

Demo:

```
>>> from future_builtins import zip
>>> prefer_indic = [[[0, 4, 6, 5, 45, 1], [2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 1]],[[0, 0.27, 6, 7, 32, 3], [0.01, 0.39, 0, 0, 0, 0]]]
>>> [[sum(zipped) for zipped in zip(*column)] for column in zip(*prefer_indic)]
[[0, 4.27, 12, 12, 77, 4], [2.01, 3.39, 5, 6, 7, 1]]
```

Comment: can u write: summed = [[sum(zipped) for zipped in zip(*column)] for column in zip(*prefer_indic)] in more than 1 line so that i can see whtats going on exactly?i mean nested loops. And actually can u explain what each line does?

Comment: @ThanosSmar: see http://pastebin.com/Yx1Uw9Gj for a version with nested `for` loops.

Answer (score 0):

I would define a function that adds two lists, then use a list comprehension to compute your desired result:

```
def add_lists(a, b):
    return list(x+y for x, y in zip(a, b))

s = list(add_lists(*l) for l in zip(*prefer_indic))
```

For you example

```
prefer_indic = [[[0, 4, 6, 5, 45, 1], [2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 1]],[[0, 0.27, 6, 7, 32, 3], [0.01, 0.39, 0, 0, 0, 0]]]
```

the result will be

```
[[0, 4.27, 12, 12, 77, 4], [2.01, 3.39, 5, 6, 7, 1]]
```